# Encoding an array of strings into a single string

Tags: c

You're given an array of strings where each character in the string is lowercase. Each character and the length of each string is randomly generated. Encode the string such that:
1. The encoded output is a single string with minimum possible length
2. You should be able to decode the string later

I am thinking the mention of each character being lowercase is key here. Since there are only 26 lowercase characters, maybe we can encode them using 5 bits instead of 8 bits and then pack them. But I am not sure how to implement this bit packing while looping over the array of strings

Comment: The problem is under specified. What is the purpose of the encoding and how will the solution be evaluated?  The trivial solution is to concatenate them  separated by spaces.

Comment: Are you familiar with bitwise operations? https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators

Comment: I think  they want you to find a way to encode each two characters into one byte, i guess, you need to explain more

Comment: @ddyer: We want an encoded output which has a minimum possible length (as mentioned in condition 1). Just concatenating doesn't seem efficient enough.

Comment: Optimum compression requires much more information about the data to be compressed, and also about the representation of the underlying strings.  If you assert that the original characters are random (and therefore non compressible) you could convert everything into a single base 27 bignum, then represent that as a stream of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

For 26 characters and a separator you could use base32. Basically concatenate the strings with a delimiter and then do a base32 *decode* - should be easy to find code for that. Just do not use those characters that result in 4-5 zeros in binary so that you do not accidentally have the null terminator in the middle of your string.

For decoding you'll do base32 *encode* and then split the string at delimiters.